# New relic for android: can new relic track http requests made using loopj (android-async-http)?

Tags: android, newrelic, loopj

I'm using [loopj](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http) to make http requests in my android app. I've recently added new relic and so far I don't see any of my app's http requests showing up in the dashboard. I do see other data streaming through new relic, but nothing on http requests.

Does newrelic even support http requests made with loopj or is there something special I need to do in order for it to work?

Comment: Added one Unique Key generated by New Relic into your Project?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this library requires the apache library directly.  Currently New Relic does not instrument org.http.apache.  If this is something you want to see New Relic do you will want to open a ticket with them at support.newrelic.com and request a feature request.

Comment: Was this every submitted as a feature request?  I'm looking for this feature as well.